# Removing the L from F_CPU in assembly

Tags: arduino-ide, assembly, compiler

I am developing a mixed c++ /asm project.
In the asm I am using F_CPU to do some busy waiting as follows. However, by default, the F_CPU is defined with a trailing L (for long). The asm is not able to cope with the L. I can fix this by manually defining a new define in the asm,  but that's a pretty dirty solution. What's the correct way to fix this?

```
.macro _delay_1u 
.rept (F_CPU/1000000)
nop
.endr
.endm
```

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! As a regular user of this network, you know how these sites work. Unfortunately, your issue does not seem to be about Arduino, I suggest to read "[ask]". Please clarify the relation, and while you're at it, add the compiler and assembler versions you are using. (Disclaimer: I did not vote down.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I am not mistaken,  F_CPU is a define provided by the Arduino environment.

Comment: Actually, it is a standard macro for avrgcc/avrlibc and not specific to Arduino. If that is your issue's only connection to Arduino, you might want to ask on [so] instead. It looks as an general GNU assembler question, which AFAIK does not accept suffices on integer literals.

Comment: That is indeed the culprit. Since pretty much any single arduino project defines F_CPU, I hoped it was a commonly encountered problem. I did not find any answers googling, though. Probably having time critical sections written in asm is less common than one would imagine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): You want to busy-wait some cycles depending on the system's clock frequency. You think you can realize that with (inline) assembly and a repetition macro. But as you found, the assembler does not accept C literals with suffixes, as it has no usage for the type information.

However, this is a possible solution to do busy-wait in C++: [built-in functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Built-in-Functions.html) of the compiler. In this case you want to use `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles()`.

This simple sketch shows the effectively generated machine code. It contains some calls of `digitalWrite()` to separate the different delays.

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  // delay 1us
  __builtin_avr_delay_cycles(F_CPU / 1000000UL);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  // delay 1 cycle
  __builtin_avr_delay_cycles(1UL);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  // delay 10 cycles
  __builtin_avr_delay_cycles(10UL);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  // delay 100 cycles
  __builtin_avr_delay_cycles(100UL);
}
```

Commonly you will not have access to the intermediately generated files, because the IDE uploads the resulting machine code directly to the target. However, as long as the IDE is running, you can access the files from some temporary location. In my case, this is the path "/tmp/arduino_build_119348", and I copied the linked sketch to save it. It is an ELF file named "test.ino.elf".

The tool "avr-objdump" (exists in your Arduino IDE installation) disassembles the binary code of `loop()` for further investigation:

```
avr-objdump -d test.ino.elf
```

If you want, you can redirect the output into a file.

The relevant part is this quite at the end:

```
 2c4:   81 e0           ldi r24, 0x01   ; 1
 2c6:   0e 94 70 00     call    0xe0    ; 0xe0 <digitalWrite.constprop.0>
 2ca:   85 e0           ldi r24, 0x05   ; 5
 2cc:   8a 95           dec r24
 2ce:   f1 f7           brne    .-4         ; 0x2cc <main+0xc8>
 2d0:   00 00           nop
 2d2:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
 2d4:   0e 94 70 00     call    0xe0    ; 0xe0 <digitalWrite.constprop.0>
 2d8:   00 00           nop
 2da:   81 e0           ldi r24, 0x01   ; 1
 2dc:   0e 94 70 00     call    0xe0    ; 0xe0 <digitalWrite.constprop.0>
 2e0:   83 e0           ldi r24, 0x03   ; 3
 2e2:   8a 95           dec r24
 2e4:   f1 f7           brne    .-4         ; 0x2e2 <main+0xde>
 2e6:   00 00           nop
 2e8:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
 2ea:   0e 94 70 00     call    0xe0    ; 0xe0 <digitalWrite.constprop.0>
 2ee:   81 e2           ldi r24, 0x21   ; 33
 2f0:   8a 95           dec r24
 2f2:   f1 f7           brne    .-4         ; 0x2f0 <main+0xec>
 2f4:   00 00           nop
```

The different delays are clearly visible. The following parts have the number of cycles in parentheses.

Since the system's clock of my chosen target is 16 MHz, the delay of 1us needs to wait 16 cycles:

```
 2ca:   85 e0           ldi r24, 0x05   ; (1)
 2cc:   8a 95           dec r24         ; (1)
 2ce:   f1 f7           brne    .-4     ; (1 if not taken, 2 if taken)
 2d0:   00 00           nop             ; (1)
```

We have n<sub>Cycles</sub> = 1 + 4 * (1 + 2) + 1 + 1 + 1 = 16.

To delay 1 cycle, the compilers inserts exactly one `nop`:

```
 2d8:   00 00           nop
```

To delay more cycles, a loop is used, as before. This is the delay of 10 cycles:

```
 2e0:   83 e0           ldi r24, 0x03   ; (1)
 2e2:   8a 95           dec r24         ; (1)
 2e4:   f1 f7           brne    .-4     ; (1 if not taken, 2 if taken)
 2e6:   00 00           nop             ; (1)
```

We have n<sub>Cycles</sub> = 1 + 2 * (1 + 2) + 1 + 1 + 1 = 10.

And the delay of 100 cycles is:

```
 2ee:   81 e2           ldi r24, 0x21   ; (1)
 2f0:   8a 95           dec r24         ; (1)
 2f2:   f1 f7           brne    .-4     ; (1 if not taken, 2 if taken)
 2f4:   00 00           nop             ; (1)
```

We have n<sub>Cycles</sub> = 1 + 32 * (1 + 2) + 1 + 1 + 1 = 100.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a complement to the busybee's answer: [the avr-libc provides the
macros `_delay_ms()` and `_delay_us()`](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html) for busy-wait delays.
Internally, they use `__builtin_avr_delay_cycles()` and `F_CPU` to
provide the required number of delay cycles. For example, on an Uno,

```cpp
_delay_us(0.25);  // delay for 0.25 µs
```

compiles to

```lisp
rjmp .  ; 2 cycles
rjmp .  ; 2 cycles
```

which takes exactly 0.25 µs (4 cycles at 16 MHz) and takes
less code space than four `nop`s.

Comment: A really preferable solution! In one place I do not find again, I remember a minimum delay like 3 µs. I might have been hallucinating but I'm not an AI. :-D